# PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot

I have two entities: `User` and `Video`.

`User` have such field:

```
@Column(name = "favourite")
@ElementCollection(targetClass = Video.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@CollectionTable(name = "favourite_videos", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"))
private Set<Video> favourite;
```

A `user` can add a video to his collection. 
However, when another `user` tries to add a `video` that has already been added by **another** `user`, an error occurs:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "uk_4ai4388fdjwvno9jj7u9x1h9x".
Key (favourite_id)=(17) already exists.
```

In the database it's look like:

[image]

I mean that user with another id can't add videos with id's 17 and 18, or any other id of video, which has already been added by another user. The question is how to make sure that users can add videos that other users already have? I want the `Video` entity not to belong to just one user.

Comment: The primary key for the table needs to be the combination of user_id and favourite_id rather than just one of the two columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your table `favourite_videos` the primary key is `favourite_id`. So in this case there cannot be another tuple where it has a `favourite_id` used in a previous tuple. (a tuple is one record (one row))

You can avoid this problem by making a composite primary key by making the combination of `user_id` and `favourite_id` as the primary key.